# how to stop and start AWS EC2 instance automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

I'm a beginner in using AWS.

I just want to stop and start several EC2 instances automatically and periodically(Not reboot).

Is there any recommended way to do this?

Comment: AWS Lambda is a good option since it has enough free tier access, if you program it correctly you can start and stop an EC2 instance using Cron at no cost if it's on a daily basis. Check out lambda pricing to see their new unit of charge called GB-second :: RAM - time of execution

Comment: Why don't you want to reboot? Do you understand that when you stop an instance (rather than terminate it), the instance is shut down, not put to sleep? There is no sleep option in AWS (that would tie up resources).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Amazon recently (Feb 2018) released the EC2 instance scheduler tool:

> The AWS Instance Scheduler is a simple AWS-provided solution that
>   enables customers to easily configure custom start and stop schedules
>   for their Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2) and Amazon
>   Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) instances. The solution is
>   easy to deploy and can help reduce operational costs for both
>   development and production environments. Customers who use this
>   solution to run instances during regular business hours can save up to
>   70% compared to running those instances 24 hours a day.

I had this up and running in my account in 15 minutes; very simple to use, and practically free.

https://aws.amazon.com/answers/infrastructure-management/instance-scheduler/

Comment: I wanted to suggest scheduled autoscaling, but I am not sure if it is possible to define 0 minimum instance count. The instance scheduler seems indeed simpler

Comment: Cloudformation is very non-intuitive, maybe update this answer to how to use Cloudformation to schedule because their documentation is bad

Comment: Here is a more detailed answer https://serverfault.com/questions/867642/how-to-start-and-stop-aws-ec2-instance-based-on-a-time-based-schedule

Answer (score 4):

AWS has a good doc explaining how you can achieve this using Lambda and Cloudwatch events. You can refer it - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/

This solution can be modified to get the EC2 list dynamically, or operate on a set of instances which can be identified based on a certain tag.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do that using AWS Lambda. You can select the trigger in Cloudwatch which runs on Cron expressions on UTC.

Here is a related link https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/start-stop-lambda-cloudwatch/

Another alternative is to use `awscli` which is available from `pip`, `apt-get`, `yum` or `brew`, and then running `aws configure` with your credentials from IAM and executing the following bash script, to stop an EC2 that has been tagged with `Name: Appname` and `Value: Appname Prod`. You can use `awscli` to tag your instances or tag it manually from the AWS console. `aws ec2 stop-instances` will stop the instance and `jq` is used to filter the json query and fetch the correct instance id using the tags from `aws ec2 describe-instances`.

To verify that `aws configure` was successful and returns json output run `aws ec2 describe-instances` and your running instance id should be there in the output. Here is a sample output

```
{
    "Reservations": [
        {
            "Instances": [
                {
                    "Monitoring": {
                        "State": "disabled"
                    },
                    "PublicDnsName": "ec2-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
                    "State": {
                        "Code": xx,
                        "Name": "running"
                    },
                    "EbsOptimized": false,
                    "LaunchTime": "20xx-xx-xxTxx:16:xx.000Z",
                    "PublicIpAddress": "xx.127.24.xxx",
                    "PrivateIpAddress": "xxx.31.3.xxx",
                    "ProductCodes": [],
                    "VpcId": "vpc-aaxxxxx",
                    "StateTransitionReason": "",
                    "InstanceId": "i-xxxxxxxx",
                    "ImageId": "ami-xxxxxxx",
                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-xxxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal",
                    "KeyName": "node",
                    "SecurityGroups": [
                        {
                            "GroupName": "xxxxxx",
                            "GroupId": "sg-xxxx"
                        }
                    ],
                    "ClientToken": "",
                    "SubnetId": "subnet-xxxx",
                    "InstanceType": "t2.xxxxx",
                    "NetworkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "Status": "in-use",
                            "MacAddress": "0x:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
                            "SourceDestCheck": true,
                            "VpcId": "vpc-xxxxxx",
                            "Description": "",
                            "NetworkInterfaceId": "eni-xxxx",
                            "PrivateIpAddresses": [
                                {
                                    "PrivateDnsName": "ip-xx.ap-south-1.compute.internal",
                                    "PrivateIpAddress": "xx.31.3.xxx",
                                    "Primary": true,
                                    "Association": {
                                        "PublicIp": "xx.127.24.xxx",
                                        "PublicDnsName": "ec2-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
                                        "IpOwnerId": "xxxxx"
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "PrivateDnsName": "ip-xxx-31-3-xxx.ap-south-1.compute.internal",
                            "Attachment": {
                                "Status": "attached",
                                "DeviceIndex": 0,
                                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                                "AttachmentId": "xxx",
                                "AttachTime": "20xx-xx-30Txx:16:xx.000Z"
                            },
                            "Groups": [
                                {
                                    "GroupName": "xxxx",
                                    "GroupId": "sg-xxxxx"
                                }
                            ],
                            "Ipv6Addresses": [],
                            "OwnerId": "xxxx",
                            "PrivateIpAddress": "xx.xx.xx.xxx",
                            "SubnetId": "subnet-xx",
                            "Association": {
                                "PublicIp": "xx.xx.xx.xxx",
                                "PublicDnsName": "ec2-xx.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com",
                                "IpOwnerId": "xxxx"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "SourceDestCheck": true,
                    "Placement": {
                        "Tenancy": "default",
                        "GroupName": "",
                        "AvailabilityZone": "xx"
                    },
                    "Hypervisor": "xxx",
                    "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                        {
                            "DeviceName": "/dev/xxx",
                            "Ebs": {
                                "Status": "attached",
                                "DeleteOnTermination": true,
                                "VolumeId": "vol-xxx",
                                "AttachTime": "20xxx-xx-xxTxx:16:xx.000Z"
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "Architecture": "x86_64",
                    "RootDeviceType": "ebs",
                    "RootDeviceName": "/dev/xxx",
                    "VirtualizationType": "xxx",
                    "Tags": [
                        {
                            "Value": "xxxx centxx",
                            "Key": "Name"
                        }
                    ],
                    "AmiLaunchIndex": 0
                }
            ],
            "ReservationId": "r-xxxx",
            "Groups": [],
            "OwnerId": "xxxxx"
        }
    ]
}
```

The following bash script is `stop-ec2.sh` in `/home/centos/cron-scripts/`

```
(instance=$(aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[].Instances | select(.[].Tags[].Value | startswith("Appname Prod") ) |  select(.[].Tags[].Key == "Appname") |  {InstanceId: .[].InstanceId, PublicDnsName: .[].PublicDnsName, State: .[].State, LaunchTime: .[].LaunchTime, Tags: .[].Tags}  | [.]' | jq -r .[].InstanceId) && aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids ${instance} )
```

Run the file using `sh /home/centos/cron-scripts/stop-ec2.sh` and verify that the EC2 instance gets stopped. To debug run `aws ec2 describe-instances | jq '.Reservations[].Instances | select(.[].Tags[].Value | startswith("Appname Prod") ) |  select(.[].Tags[].Key == "Appname") |  {InstanceId: .[].InstanceId, PublicDnsName: .[].PublicDnsName, State: .[].State, LaunchTime: .[].LaunchTime, Tags: .[].Tags}  | [.]' | jq -r .[].InstanceId` and see that it returns the correct instance ID which has been tagged.

Then in `crontab -e` the following line can be added

`30 14 * * * sh /home/centos/cron-scripts/stop-ec2.sh >> /tmp/stop`

which will log the output to `/tmp/stop`. The `30 14 * * *` is the UTC cron expression that you can check in `https://crontab.guru/`

Answer (score 1):

Lambda script to stop instance:

```
import json
import boto3

# Enter the region your instances are in. Include only the region without specifying Availability Zone; e.g., 'us-east-1'
region = 'us-east-1'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

    filter = [{'Name': 'tag:Name', 'Values': ['****-env']}]  //give instance name here in place of ****-env

    instances = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=filter)

    #ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)


    stop_instance = instances.get('Reservations')[0].get('Instances')[0].get('InstanceId')
    stop_instances = []
    stop_instances.append(stop_instance)

    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=stop_instances)
```

Lambda script to start instance:

```
import json
import boto3

# Enter the region your instances are in. Include only the region without specifying Availability Zone; e.g., 'us-east-1'
region = 'us-east-1'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)

    filter = [{'Name': 'tag:Name', 'Values': ['****-env']}]

    instances = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=filter)

    #ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)


    start_instance = instances.get('Reservations')[0].get('Instances')[0].get('InstanceId')
    start_instances = []
    start_instances.append(start_instance)

    ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=start_instances)
```

Answer (score 0):

ASG scheduler is the best and easiest option to mange the EC2 instance if you are using ASG. If not using ASG, then you can use either AWS instance scheduler CF solution or lambda with cloudwatch Cron event.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use EventScheduler and it is all covered now

First create a iAM policy and add following json in it

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "ec2Stop",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:StopInstances",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

Now create iAM role, select custom trust policy and add following json in trust policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "ec2Stop",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:StopInstances",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

Now go to Amazon event bridge, create a scheduler and specify scheduler details, you can use cron for recurring. Then in select target select All Apis and search for ec2. Then search for stopInstances API. Select it and add you instances IDs. At the end attach the role to it and boom it's all done to stop instance automatically

Similarly following is the policy for start instances rest of the flow remains the same

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "EC2Start",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:StartInstances",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}